# CSS unwanted white space at bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Context:** 
I am making a website where the white bit running down the middle (the 'wrapper' div) is supposed to be the background for all the content on the page, whereas the red bit (the 'body') running down the sides operates as a border. If I get rid of the 100% bottom-padding from the 'wrapper' div, the content I have on my website ends up with a background of red (background of the 'body' instead of the 'wrapper'). Nevertheless, if I have the 100% bottom-padding on the 'wrapper' div I can scroll further than the bottom of the page (all my content fits on one page at the moment, whereas I can scroll for at least two pages).

Please accordingly explain how I can keep the content's background as the wrapper div without the scrolling ability going beyond the end of the content. For example, in the code presented, there should be no ability to scroll down beyond the first screen because there is no content. The amount I can scroll on the code presented is the same as the amount I can scroll on my website.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bob</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" contents="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


<style>

body {
height: 100%;
background-color:red;
margin:0 auto;
}

#wrapper {
width:600px;
height: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
background-color: white;
padding-top:8px;
padding-bottom:100%;  /* removed and white space at bottom removed */
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right:20px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could not produce the issue (Chrome 45.0 on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite)

Comment: Why is there a need for %100 padding? This could be a hint you should find a better way.

Comment: @agentNil If I get rid of the 100% bottom-padding for 'div wrapper', the content I have on my website in the middle section (currently backgrounded by the white of 'wrapper') ends up with a background of red (background of the 'body' instead of the 'wrapper').

Comment: Could not produce issue in chrome and firefox, also at top `<!doctype html>
<html>` remove `<html>`

Comment: @Kwarrtz Again, I am not sure I was clear with my original post so I have edited and restated the issue.

Comment: @JonnyBoy Where is the red coming from? Maybe you should look into that.

Comment: @agentNil the red is coming from the 'body'.

Comment: @JonnyBoy You should create a div and move the red property to that and let the body be white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why there is scrolling is because you are setting the `padding-bottom` to 100%. [Paddings and margins are calculated using `width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties) as a reference and not the `height`:

> **'padding-top', 'padding-right', 'padding-bottom', 'padding-left'**
>
> Percentages:      refer to width of containing block

---

As per why if you remove the `padding-bottom:100%;`, then `#wrapper` takes only a little bit instead of the whole screen (as you expect because you have `height:100%`): [the height is calculated based on the height of the containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **'height'**
>
> <percentage>
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

Right now you are setting the `body` to a height of 100%, but you are not setting the height of `html` anywhere. So the `body` is taking 100% of the height of the parent (`html`) that is nothing. To fix that problem, just apply the same style to `body` and `html`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

---

So to achieve what you want: add `html`'s height, and remove the unnecessary `padding-bottom`. Like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bob</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" contents="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


    <style>

      html,body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color:red;
        margin:0 auto;
      }

      #wrapper {
        width:300px;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color: white;
        padding-top:8px;
        /*padding-bottom:100%;  /* removed and white space at bottom removed */
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        box-
      }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

There is still a small scroll because `#wrapper` has a `padding-top:8px`.

Comment: Cheers Alvaro. Perfect response - sorted out my problem. Kind regards